# MSACCESS - Closing Form edits 1st entry

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have table with 3 Columns. It has a AutoNumber Primary ID (cboID), A Text Column (txtLocation), and a Number Column (txtCount).

From this table, I made a form that has a combobox and two text fields. When the combobox is clicked, it shows a list of all the cboID's. After selecting one of the choices, it autopopulates the two other text fields with it's respective Location and Count info. I also have an update statement/save button that allows the user to edit one of the entries, press save, and update one or both the fields.

Here's the statement I have.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

Dim strSQL As String


strSQL = "UPDATE aDuh SET Location = '" & Me.txtLocation & "', Count = '" & Me.txtCount & "' WHERE ID = '" & Me.cboID & "'"


DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

End Sub
```

The updating has no problems, but the form updates the 1st entry when I close it. Lets say I just finished editing the third entry and I'm done editing. I want to close the form and do something else. However, I close the form (I've tried putting a button and just closing the tab) and the 1st entry in the table is updated with the third entry. So basically, my last edited entry edits properly, but when the form is closed, it also updates the 1st record. Any idea of how to fix this? (If this isn't clear please let me know and I'll try to clarify)

I'm thinking of writing a statement for the On Close event but I'm not sure what to put.

EDIT: Extra Info

Right now, this table only has three records. In the form, when I click the combobox, it has the drop down list of the three records. Lets say I clicked the second one. After clicking it, the Location field is populated with the related info and same with the count field. Now lets say the current value in the count field is "9" and I want to change it to 4. I type in 4, press update and I'm prompted with a  box saying "are you sure you want to update 1 row". I press yes, and it updates. Updating works fine, its just when I close. I'll give two examples

1) I just edited the second record, when I close, it doesnt prompt anything, it just closes smoothly, but when I check the information, the first and second record are now the exact same.

2) Lets say I just edited the first record. When I close it, a window pops up saying "Write Conflict, This record has been changed by another user since you started editing it. If you save the record, you will overwrite the changes". It then has three options, Save Record, Copy to Clipboard and Drop Changes.

Oh and how i'm making it autopopulate, I have the code:

```
Private Sub cboID_Change()
Me.txtLocation = Me.cboID.Column(1)
Me.txtCount = Me.cboID.Column(2)

End Sub
```

Hopefully this clarifies a bit more. :(

Comment: Is your combobox bound? (I mean what is the `ControlSource` property set to?)

Comment: Its blank. That means unbound right?

Comment: Yes it is - I don't think you need to use the close event, however you need to provide more information about what is going on

Comment: Check my edit up there^ hopefully its a bit better? :/

Comment: It seems that none of your controls are bound. Ms Access forms usually have a `RecordSource` and then the controls are bound to fields in that `RecordSource`. The UPDATE button would not be necessary then as Access does all the updating.

Comment: The location and count are bound, but the id combobox isnt. If it bound too, it starts to try and overwrite the ID column everytime i open the combobox and select another record